# How to fix Facebook Graph API returning 'reorder_pids is required'

Tags: ruby, facebook

so i have a problem in updating a post using my app sending this link via post gives me a problem

https://graph.facebook.com/{post-id}
=> post data are: {message:"a new updated message"}

it returns this JSON code requiring me to specify 'reorder_pids' paramter.

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) The parameter reorder_pids is required","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}
```

I'am trying this out at Facebook Graph API Explorer and its not working. when i try to specify a vale to reoder_pids it stil throws an error that said 'reorder_pids' must be an array.

what is the workaround for this problem? did i do something wrong on my POST parameter request?

Comment: Please file a bug here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/trending/

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by doing this:

```
POST /v2.5/{user_or_page_id}_{post_id}
?access_token={token}
&message={new_message}
```

Notice how the `user_id` (or page_id) is prefixed to the `post_id` and the version is updated. It seems like multiple problems accessing Edges on the API can be solved using the `{user_or_page_id}_{post_id}`. But no thanks to FB for telling anybody.

Source:
[How should we retrieve an individual post now that /[post-id] is deprecated in v2.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353591/how-should-we-retrieve-an-individual-post-now-that-post-id-is-deprecated-in-v)